# Python spline interpolation with two different dataset

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

I have a dataset (stellar spectrum) with around 4000 points. I want to interpolate the `x` and `y` data (same length) with this new list, `x_new` which has nearly 17000 points.

I have found [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) thas does this job, except it is a piecewise linear interpolation. I want it to be smooth.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) has a `kind` parameter that can be set to e.g. `"cubic"`.

Instad of supplying the x-values you wish to interpolate on directly to this function, you do it like this:

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> y = np.exp(-x / 3.0)
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, "cubic")
>>> i = np.arange(0.5, 9.5, 1)
>>> f(i)
array([ 0.85826566,  0.61497421,  0.44064828,  0.31573829,  0.22623637,
        0.16210544,  0.11615363,  0.08322771,  0.05963526])
```

[This](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) is a scipy interpolation tutorial that might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I need to cubic option, but this scipy interpolation only takes two arguments. I need to give it three arguments like the numpy interpolation.